# Visual c++ How to sqlite3 without sqlite3.dll use

Tags: c++

How to sqlite3 dll without use? I'm imported sqlite3.h and sqlite3.lib, and error sqlite3.dll not found. Need run without sqlite3.dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how it works. If the `.lib` is compiled to be dynamically linked then it just exports the list of symbols available inside the dll but the code still resides inside the dll.

If you want to avoid using dll, you need a static version of the library, I don't know if it's already provided by sqlite, otherwise you need to compile it yourself, [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=HowToCompile) could help you.

Comment: Only sqlite3.c with sqlite3.h Could use? This solution do not need dll, but visual studio does not suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know sqlite3 is a single source file. Just add it to your build and you should be golden.

Comment: The way to resolve linking issues is not to pretend that you'll never need to link anything.

Comment: just for clarify the single source file is build artifact and deploy element which gathering from large enought source file set.